# Reading bitmap header, getting reversed values

Tags: c, bitmap

I'm trying to read the bitmap header. I have defined the following struct:

```
typedef struct  {
    char magic[2];
    char size[4];
    char reserved[4];
    char offset[4];
    char dibbytes[4];
    char width[4];
    char height[4];
    char colorplanes[2];
    char bpp[2];
    char rawsize[4];
    char hor_res[4];
    char ver_res[4];
    char colors[4];
    char important[4];
} bmp_t;
```

And I open a bitmap image with this function:

```
void open(char * filename) {
    long filesize;
    char * buffer;

    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * filesize);
    fread(buffer, 1, filesize, file);
    bmp_t * bmp = (bmp_t *) buffer;
    printf("Size in hex: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", bmp->size[0], bmp->size[1], bmp->size[2], bmp->size[3]);
    fclose(file);
}
```

To test this, I made a new bitmap, width = 1000 pixels, height = 3 pixels. The filesize is 9054 bytes. However, the output of my program is:

```
Size in hex: 5e 23 00 00
```

That's a bit strange because 0x5e23 reversed is 0x235e, which is 9054 in decimal (the correct filesize). So the values are saved in reverse. For example, if I make a 1000x1000 bitmap, I should get a filesize of 3000054 in decimal, but I get 0xf6c62d. And the reverse, 0x2dc6f6, is 3000054 (again, the correct filesize).

So I thought I could just sprintf the string in reverse and then use atoi to convert it to int:

```
sprintf(bmp->size, "%c%c%c%c", bmp->size[3], bmp->size[2], bmp->size[1], bmp->size[0]);
printf("Size reversed: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", bmp->size[0] & 0xFF, bmp->size[1] & 0xFF, bmp->size[2] & 0xFF, bmp->size[3] & 0xFF);
int size = atoi(bmp->size);`
printf("Size: %d\n", size);
```

For the image I get the following result:

```
Size reversed: 00 00 23 5e
Size: 0
```

So the sprintf is working great, my string is reversed and 0x235e is the correct answer. But the atoi doesn't work on the string, and I don't know why. Besides that, I think this method of printing a reverse string is a very strange way of reading the values.

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

**Update!**
Turns out it is an endianness problem. But how should I read it then? I just want to get an integer with the filesize (or width, height, anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because everything in memory is saved in reversed order, at least on little endian machines (x86s fall in this category). Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for details about endianness and [here](http://www.noveltheory.com/techpapers/endian.asp) if you want to know why little endian is used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how should I read it in order to get an integer with the value?

Comment: @Carlito: You have to manually reverse them or maybe try using ints instead of chars

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the real world, where different computers have different [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Reading binary fields directly is never a good idea, you need to be endian-aware.

There probably is a well-defined byte order for the BMP file format (probably little-endian due to its roots on x86), and you need to make sure you always read any multi-byte fields in the proper way.

UPDATE: [Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header):

> All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format (i.e. least-significant byte first).>

Answer (score 0):

The storing of things in "reverse" is called the *[endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)* of the machine.  X86 machines store their bytes in *little-endian* order.

You're trying to convert a hexadecimal value with a function that converts an ASCII value to a `int`.  This is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing it wrong.

This is called little-endian data.

Read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

There is more than one way to store data in files :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how should I read it in order to get an integer with the value?

Comment: You're welcome, sorry for the delay in responding.
If you haven't sorted this already, I hope this helps:
[IBM: Writing endian-independent code in C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-) - this should cover answering your question and teach you a bit more useful and interesting stuff besides!